# is it possible to view video before drag in the editor?

Tags: video

Blender video question :

Is it possible to preview video files without drag'n drop them in the video sequencer editor ?

Thank you.

Comment: Not in the way *dedicated* video editors/ compositing apps like premiere, AE, openshot, or others allow, no I don't believe so.

Comment: Yes, thank you :)